# Trying to get property of non-object in ;laravel array displaying

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a laravel fetching controller like below,

```
public function fetchbywhere()
{

    $result=User::find(2);
    return View::make('fetchbywhere')->with('resultrow',$result);

}
```

My Model file of User.php like,

```
 use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
 use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

 class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
protected $table = 'users';
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

and my routes.php file ,

```
Route::get('select-by-where',array('as'=>'select_by_where','uses'=>'Test@fetchbywhere'));
```

and my view file named  fetchbywhere.blade.php,

```
 <title>Fetch by Where clouse</title>

 <h2>Users - Where clouse</h2>

@foreach($resultrow as $data)
<ul>
  <li>{{$data->name}}</li>
</ul>
@endforeach
```

my database have fields like

```
id|name|email|age|created_at|updated_at
```

am getting error like **Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\wamp\www\new_laravel\app\views\fetchbywhere.blade.php)**

anybody please give me a solution. t

thanks

Comment: Do you know what a non-object means, and what it means to fetch a property of a non object?

Comment: no. can u please describe me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `User::find(2)` this returns a single instance of `User` with id = 2. Or even null if it doesn't exist. In your view you are iterating over `$resultrow` as if it where a collection and not a single model.

I believe what you actually want to do is something like this:

```
$result=User::where('some-column', 'operator', 'some-value')->get();
return View::make('fetchbywhere')->with('resultrow',$result);
```

So an example could be...

```
$result=User::where('age', '>', '18')->get();
return View::make('fetchbywhere')->with('resultrow',$result);
```

...to get everybody over 18

---

Also its "where clause" not clouse ;)

#### Update

The actual use for the `find` method is to get only **one** object with the passed id (primary key in the database). It doesn't return a *collection* (list) because there no way it could find multiple rows with the same id, since the primary key is unique.

If you only want one user (by a specific id) you have to change your view to directly access the model

```
<title>Fetch by Where clouse</title>

<h2>Users - Where clouse</h2>

{{ $resultrow->name }}
```

Comment: great !, its working, but i see in laravel official documentation like amy question. what is the actual use of the find(1) in laravel, can you please...

Comment: @Jishad the find(1) means the query will get the user where id = 1 in the database

Comment: but i have a primerykey 1 as in my table, then why it is not getting output, ?